# Is there a native C++ connector for mariadb/mysql that is not just a wrapper for an older c connector?

Tags: c++, mariadb, mysql-connector

Has anyone released a native c++ connector for mariadb/mysql that is not a wrapper for a c connector api?  I've googled around and can't find anything.

The reason I ask is to judge the ultimate value of using a c++ connector versus just implementing the c connector itself without the "middle man" of the wrapper.  Every programming language is finally just a human interface between the cpu and the programmer.  Some languages are more artfully rendered and powerful than others, but they are still only interfaces.  We have...

dbase engine <- c connector <- c++ wrapper <- application

versus

dbase engine <- c connector <- application

Is the only advantage to this the fact that the programmer doesn't have to do conversions from C types to C++ types and classes on his own?

Why wouldn't I just use the old C connector and leave out the C++ wrapper?  Is there ever a performance degradation because of the "middle man"?

Comment: No, but why do you ask and why do you care? `libmysqlclient` has a C API not a C++ API

Comment: The most obvious answer seems to be the official MySQL Connector/C++ http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/ If it wraps another connector or not I do not know, but does it matter?

Comment: Sundae, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Sundae: the official C++ connector is [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html) to be above the `libmysqlclient` C library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There probably is no native C++ connector (for [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)/MariaDB), since the `libmysqlclient` has a C API, and since the network protocol between that library and the server is not very well documented or defined. That protocol is rumored to have changed several times (with versions of MySQL).

Regarding performance, it does not matter much in practice, since most of the time the SQL server is not on the same host as the client, so there is real netwoking (e.g. 1Gbit/sec ethernet) between them - which practically speaking is already a bottleneck (things could be different if the SQL server & the client are on the same host e.g. on `localhost`; but that is not very usual). A typical network interaction means kilobytes on the wire, so several milliseconds.

BTW, several (and probably most) SQL requests may require real hard disk access (at least when the entire database is big enough to not fit in RAM), which means many milliseconds. (Things are faster with SSD disks).

So in practice, it generally does not matter to go thru two layers of connectors (this costs only some dozens of microseconds).

BTW, if you are in the rare case where the data is on the same machine as your database client, you could consider [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) instead. If performance is very important to you, you might give up SQL and use indexed files à la [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)

AFAIK, indexing is much more important performance-wise than the two layers of connectors: a good indexing may avoid several disk accesses!

<sup>Of course, I am thinking of large enough databases which do not fit in RAM. If your database is only a hundred megabytes, everything sit in RAM. And I am not an expert in databases or in MySQL</sup>

Since [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) (& [Mariadb](https://downloads.mariadb.org/)) is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could study the source code of `libsqlclient`, understand all the details of the protocol, and reimplement it (in a free GPL licensed library) in genuine C++ (or in Ocaml, etc.). But I don't think it is worth the effort.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  BTW, it would be interesting to study the nuts and bolts of database interaction.  Does anyone know of a book (or any resource) on actually interfacing on the low level with a database engine?  Do db engines just take the text SQL statements at their listening port?

Comment: database servers are "transforming" ("compiling") SQL requests into some lower procedural form (bytecode)

Comment: Is SQL just an interpreted language passed to the server one line at a time?

Comment: Every SQL request is "compiled" into elementary steps (see the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) statement). Prepared requests are "compiled" once.

Comment: Okay.  I'll look around. Thanks for the lead anyway.  Somebody gave me a down vote on the original question, so I'm going to stop while I'm not so far behind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: https://launchpad.net/mariadb++

But there's no documentation and it hasn't seen any updates since it was first released over two years go.